# Can one Entity contain two different Entities of the same type, uniquely accessible?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, database-design

Forget databases and tables for a moment. Say I have a class `Spaceship` and a class `Person`. If I am writing the `Contract` model, I might do this:

```
public class Spaceship {
  public string LicensePlate { get; set; } //
  public string Destination { get; set; }  //Regular old data
  public Person Captain { get; set; }
  public Person Engineer { get; set; }
}
```

because the captain and the engineer are both people, and while their relevant information may be slightly different, they'll stay the most DRY if they're the same type.

But what if I wanted to make this kind of relationship in an Entity Framework? If I were drawing it up in Entity designer, I would make a relationship like this:

```
 ---------------------                   ---------------------
|      Spaceship      |                 |        Person       |
|---------------------|                 |---------------------|
|    LicensePlate     |                 |    Name             |
|    Destination      |                 |    PhoneNumber      |
|---------------------|                 |---------------------|
|Navigation Properties|                 |Navigation Properties|
|    People           |1---------------*|    Spaceship        |
 ---------------------                   ---------------------
```

But this is not the same thing. Because while the two `People` can accurately share the same class, their relationship with the `Spaceship` is fundamentally different. I want to have a dbContext where I can say

```
Spaceship Enterprise = new Spaceship();
Enterprise.Captain = People.Find("Kirk");
Enterprise.Engineer = People.Find("Scotty");
```

Is that too much to ask? I mean, sure, there are other ways. `Person` could have a `Role` that would be "Captain" or "Engineer," and then you could lump them all into `Enterprise.People`. You could even make a `GetCaptain()` method on `Spaceship` if you need to access the captain a lot.

But, in the interest of education,

1. **Is that possible?**
2. **If so, what are the consequences on the actual database schema?**
3. **What's the best way?**

Comment: It is possible, you have to define in your `ModelBuilder` using the Fluent API what the mapping is for those virtual navigation properties.

Comment: As Travis said, all this is possible. If you have doubts about how, I suggest you use db first approach. I find it more intuitive.

Comment: Anyone care to expound? I know how the schema works for the standard one-to-many relationship I showed in the diagram, but I can't think of what kind of SQL would achieve what I really want to do. So it may be possible, but I'm still looking for insight on what's really going on and whether that is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could add Engineer and Captain tables with a zero-or-one-to-one relationship with the Person table which would give you your two navigation properties for the Spaceship. This approach could be useful if your model changes and either sub-type ends up requiring new properties or methods.

Comment: So you're saying `Enterprise.Engineer.Person = `...?

Comment: Yes, though if the Engineer and Captain entities really are always going to have identical properties and methods, I am not sure I see a problem with the code you gave to start. This might make things clearer to a certain extent and would be flexible to changes. Imagine Enterprise.Captain.Engage()

Comment: I agree - I like the code I started with. But it doesn't translate particularly well to SQL designing paradigms. I wasn't sure if there were any caveats from a SQL Server perspective. Or any perspective.

Comment: I don't really see a problem with it from an SQL perspective, though you might need to watch for unique values depending what you have planned. I guess that's part of why OOP is so useful: it allows you to abstract away from the data model as your software requires. It's a good question.